# Establishing a connection with DB2 using UNIX

Tags: unix, db2, database-connection

I am relatively new to the scripting language. I need to update a table based on a particular column.
Is there a way to connect a db2 database using UNIX? The details I have with me are the database name, the server name, and port details.
Are the above details sufficient for connecting to db2 using UNIX?

Comment: If "Unix" means shell or command line, then you need the Db2 client. It's in the docs.

Comment: it is a unix shell scripts

Comment: Ok, see my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Db2 offers a command line processor (CLP)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010412.html). That utility can be used to connect to Db2 from a shell. It is part both of the Db2 server packages as well as the client. See the [installation instructions in the Db2 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0023452.html) for details and links to obtain the installation package for your platform.